# python map file into virtual blocks / seek / map back

Tags: python, file, dictionary, io, block

Is there an easy way in `Python` to break down a file into virtual 4MB blocks and separate them, later on do `seek()`s, `read()`s and `write()`s in the file and map back all blocks to one file?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Comment: You cold use the external `split` program if you're on linux, instead of writing code that does basically the same thing.

Comment: I want to mimic POSIX compliance within Python programmatically. I can not work with external commands. Sry.

Comment: If the file fits in the memory you can use `mmap` https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html to map chunks of the file in the memory. This chunks behave as if they where separate arrays. Writes to a specific chunk will be does to the matching position within the file.

Comment: Thank you for the hint Sebastion! What I have is a list of 4MB blocks and I want do build a POSIX compliant set arround it. mmap looks interesting if you have the file already. But how to solve the other way arround if there are just the blocks and you want to virtually construct the file? - Idea is to not touch all needed blocks, just those which are in question by the POSIX functions.